# How to dump part of my database in Django

Tags: mysql, django, testing

I want to use exist data in my database for unit test in Django. The database is too big for a test so I want to dump part of the data.

Is there any way to dump part of them? (my database is MySQL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this part `models.MyModel.objects.all()` to get selective data in fixtures.

```
from django.core import serializers
from myproject.myapp import models
data = serializers.serialize("json", models.MyModel.objects.all())
out = open("mymodel.json", "w")
out.write(data)
out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) e.g.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --format=json --indent=2 --exclude=admin --exclude=sessions > test_db.json
```

Here I am dumping everything in the database excluding the admin and sessions tables (my guess is you might not need those), into a json file named `test_db.json`. I'm also using an indent of 2 spaces to make the file more easy to inspect by eye.

Comment: Does this allow to dump part of the data ?

Comment: If you don't supply an appname like so: `python manage.py dumpdata name_of_my_app`, it dumps everything. As you can see though from above by using `--exclude` you can tell it which apps or models to exclude or you can use `--database` to just dump a given database,

Comment: Yup, you're right, --exclude also takes models (appName.Model).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **mysqldump** :

You will need to lookup all the names of the tables you want to dump. To get the full list you can use :

`mysqlshow db_name`

Then run :

`mysqldump db_name table_1 table_2 table_3 table_4`

This command will output the result to the standard output, if you want it to write to a file, use `--result-file=/path/to/file`

See also the full documentation for mysqldump : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html